# FIREBASE: load firebase.json from another folder

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an nx-monorepo.

- ran `firebase init` ==> .firebaserc and firebase.json were created at root
- according to docs you can reference firebase.json in another folder, just by adding a `--config=PATH` to firebase commands
- moved firebase.json into `test` folder at root level, just to test it
- When I run `firebase emulators: start --config test/firebase.json`, I'm getting the following: `Error: Could not load config file test/firebase.json`


  **QUESTION: Is there even a way to run emulators, serve, deploy, etc. - without keeping the firebase.json at root? Should it not be possible with the --config param?**

Comment: Can you link to the docs that reference adding a `--config=PATH` variable?

Comment: @Chris https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli - "While firebase.json is used by default, you can pass the --config PATH flag to specify an alternate configuration file."